# pass variable to function via bind in react component

Tags: reactjs

Below is the code snippet from a [navigation menu example](http://jsfiddle.net/dannymarkov/vfcfndxj/1/), which is from this [blogpost](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/07/5-practical-examples-for-learning-facebooks-react-framework/). What I don't understand is the use of self variable and bind method.

I think `this` refers to MenuExample when it is stored as `self`, but I don't know how `this` changed inside `<li>`?

Also why is that `onClick={this.clicked(index)}` doesn't work? In this context what does `this` refers to?

```
var MenuExample = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return { focused: 0 };
},

clicked: function(index){

    // The click handler will update the state with
    // the index of the focused menu entry

    this.setState({focused: index});
},

render: function() {

    // Here we will read the items property, which was passed
    // as an attribute when the component was created

    var self = this;

    // The map method will loop over the array of menu entries,
    // and will return a new array with <li> elements.

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>{ this.props.items.map(function(m, index){

                var style = '';

                if(this.state.focused == index){
                    style = 'focused';
                }

                // Notice the use of the bind() method. It makes the
                // index available to the clicked function:

                return <li className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;

            }) }

            </ul>

            <p>Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]}</p>
        </div>
    );

}
});

// Render the menu component on the page, and pass an array with menu options

ReactDOM.render(
    <MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact us'] } />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-aa458df8c136#.fd5z0vmjl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick={this.clicked(index)}` doesn't work because onClick expects a function, not a result of it. Normally, in a click handler, an event will be passed to it, but here they are using bind() to override that behavior and pass the component and the index as 'this' and the first argument.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: `onClick={this.clicked.bind(this, index)}` is also wrong, is `self` variable necesary, if so, why? `this` originally refers to the component and inside onClick it changes to what?

Comment: `this` variable is context dependent. By assigning self and using bind() they are making sure that the right value is passed as `this` into clicked()

Comment: To understand this better, I suggest you add console.log(this) to your clicked() and try a few different variants

Comment: Okay.. I think `this` has becomed undefined inside `onClick` since it is a simple call inside map function, so it needs to save `self` variable beforehand.

Comment: I don't think this is undefined inside click(), it gets assigned the element that was clicked, but they want it to point to the component and not to the element. Anyway, bind() is used to change the meaning of this inside click()